# ios Music player

Tags: iphone

Hi
I am working on an Alarm Clock app..
I am using MPMediaPickerController class,using it I was able to pick and the mp3 file but not able to get the path of the file to play when UINotification gets called.
Can anyone suggest something..??

Thanks

Comment: put some code friend...so that we can find where is your problem..

Comment: -(void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection 
{
 
 

 
musicPlayer =[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
 [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
 [musicPlayer play];
 
 MPMediaItem *item = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
 url_song = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
 NSLog(@"Path for the song is %@",url_song);

I want the url of selected song to be passed to UIlocalNotification,so that it should play whenevr the notification come...

Answer (score 2):

You're not given the path, you're given a URL, in such a form as AVFoundation should understand it. I think part of the reason you never get a path is to protect DRM content. Anyway, your delegate should drill the returned MPMediaItemCollection down to the MPMediaItem you want, you can then use `valueForProperty` to get the suitable URL.

Example code to play whatever is selected in an MPMediaPickerController immediately (typed for the first time here, please comment if I've made any errors):

```
// delegate method, to receive the result of the MPMediaPickerController
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker 
  didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    // use the first item in the collection
    MPMediaItem *item = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];

    // get the URL to the MP3
    NSURL *URL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    // URL uses a proprietary scheme, but AVFoundation understands it, so...
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                    initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:NULL];
    [player play];
    /* NB: player will leak. Do something more sensible in your code */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response..One more thing I wanted to clarify that can I pass this url to UILocalNotification to select the song name like...
notif1.soundName =url_song;

Comment: Hi 
Someone pls help me out, i am stuck..

Comment: I do not think you can use soundName property to play a selected MP3. In the property description it says that it can only play 30 seconds certain media file that is in the bundle of your app. I do not know how to make a mp3 alarm clock either, I am also searching for it right now.